# How can I update data with javascript d3?

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I am making a plot with different circles on it. Each circle has a fixed position, but the size of each circle can be changed seperately via an html input field.

The code is use for the input field is this:

```
<input type="text" id="size1" class="size" value="" style="width: 30px;">
```

I have saved the data in this dataset:

```
var dataset = [{name: "circle1", xpos: -413, ypos: 278, color: "black", radius: $('#size1').val(),},
            {name: "circle2", xpos: -161, ypos: 290, color: "black", radius: $('#size2').val(),}];
```

This is how I draw the circle:

```
function drawCircle () {
            svg.selectAll("circle").remove();
            svg.selectAll("circle")
               .data(dataset)
               .enter()
               .append("svg:circle")
               .attr("cx", function(d){
                        return xScale(d.xpos);})
               .attr("cy", function(d){
                        return yScale(d.ypos);})
               .attr("r", function (d){            
                        return rScale(d.radius);})                          
               .attr("fill", "rgb(100,0,0)")
               .attr("opacity", "0.7");
        }
```

Lastly I make a trigger that when something changes, the circle is drawn again:

```
$('.size').change(function(){
            radius = $(this).val(); 
            svg.selectAll("circle")
               .transition()
               .duration(750)
               .attr("r", function (d){            
                        return rScale(radius);})
        });
```

This way when I change a value in #size1 or #size2, both circles are redrawn with the value that is last inputted.

My question is: How can I update the dataset in a way that each circle will 'listen' to his own input field?

Comment: How do you determine the "own circle"? Btw, make your `radius` variable local

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you have multiple input-fields.

What you can do when you have a change on one of the fields, recreate the dataset and repaint the circles.

The static data for your dataset can be stored in a data-attribute on the input.

Like this:

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="circle1" class="size" value="" style="width: 30px;" data-circle='{"name": "circle1", "xpos": -161, "ypos": 290, "color": "black" }'>
```

**javascript**

```
function drawCircles (dataset) {
        svg.selectAll("circle").remove();
        svg.selectAll("circle")
           .data(dataset)
           .enter()
           .append("svg:circle")
           .attr("cx", function(d){
                    return xScale(d.xpos);})
           .attr("cy", function(d){
                    return yScale(d.ypos);})
           .attr("r", function (d){            
                    return rScale(d.radius);})                          
           .attr("fill", "rgb(100,0,0)")
           .attr("opacity", "0.7");
    }

$('.size').change(function(){
        var dataset = [];
        $('.size').each(function(index,item) {
          var circleData = item.data('circle');
          var circleData['radius'] = $(item).val();
          dataset.push(circleData);
        });
        drawCircles(dataset);
    });
```